# how to speed up initialization of run in firebase test lab

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

When running:

> gcloud firebase test android run --type=instrumentation --app=app.apk --test=test_app.apk

The firebase command line is stuck many minutes in "Creating individual test executions".

When debugging further it seems that the command line polls a backend "https://testing.googleapis.com:443" periodically till it get's an ok.

Is there a way to speed this up? This step can take 5 minutes and it takes unnessecary CI time

Update:

The command line was missing the part: --device model=NexusLowRes,version=29 --verbosity=debug

I analyzed the issue further. It takes about 100 sec to upload both app and test app and another 150 s to create the test execution. so i think that it is a limitation in the system and nothing can be done here. Maybe the size of the apk is limiting. It is about 200 mb and it takes a lot time to scan this.

Comment: It might be helpful to see your entire command line, like how many different devices*shards are you creating? Also, how large are your APK files?

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comment on your question asking for additional details that could affect the answer.

One option is to add `--async` to your command. This will only poll the matrix status until it verifies that the matrix is created successfully, then exit without waiting for the test to actually run.

Comment: i am looking how to make the part before the async faster. Besides this if i run async i don't know from ci when results are coming. I would be even happy if there is some paid option to get a virtual device fast as possible

Comment: You didn't post your entire command line as requested above, which makes it harder to help.
But I doubt there's much that can be done to speed this up. The time to allocate a virtual device is typically very fast. The delay you're talking about is the time needed to upload your APKs to the cloud, validate the matrix, do APK malware checks, expand the matrix into individual test executions (1 per device used), and many other pre-test processing steps. Device allocation comes after the initial "OK" is received from the backend (i.e. after the point where `--async` would cause gcloud to exit).

Comment: this is the command. I have no other stuff here.

Comment: There needs to be more to your command if you intend to use a virtual device, as you stated. If you don't specify a device with the `--device` flag, you get the default device in the FTL catalog, which is a physical Pixel 3 on API 28 (model "blueline"). At times, more tests are submitted for some physical devices than there are devices available (they are a finite resource), and that can cause delays in running your tests.

Comment: 5 minutes to get past "creating test executions" is not typical. For such a simple command, I can only assume that your APKs are quite large and therefore take a long time to upload and validate. The results of the APK malware check are cached, so you only have to pay that cost once upon the first upload of a never-seen-before APK.

Comment: i updated the question to reflect my research